# How do i add video (.MP4) files in QnA maker?

Tags: video, azure-qna-maker

How do I add video (.mp4) files in QnA maker, that is in the answer part of the question-answer pair?
I didn't find any solution for it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. QnAMaker only supports text-based answers. You can  use a link to your video, hosted elsewhere, in the answer, and use other software, such as a bot, to render it to the customer by intercepting that link and transforming it into a medium such as a card.

[image: No multimedia]